# WSO2-IS 5.11.0 - CORS management service error when intercepting an HTTP request - MySQL DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to access carbon's login page of WSO2 Identity Server and I'm receiving an error when I change the default database in deployment.toml. If I use h2 internal database everything works, but if I change to use a mysql database running on a docker environment it gives an error.

This works:

```
[database.identity_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2IDENTITY_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

This doesn't work

```
[database.identity_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://csm-wso2-mysqldb:3306/WSO2_IDENTITY_DB?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```

**csm-wso2-mysqldb** is a docker container name

Error:

```
csm-wso2-is               | [2021-08-28 17:54:15,197] [1deadc88-3363-427e-b238-89a418231406] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve} - 
CORS management service error when intercepting an HTTP request. org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.exception.CORSManagementServiceServerException: CMS-65006
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.service.internal.impl.CORSManagerImpl.getCORSConfiguration(CORSManagerImpl.java:101)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:81)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
csm-wso2-is               |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
csm-wso2-is               |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
csm-wso2-is               |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
csm-wso2-is               | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.exception.CORSManagementServiceServerException: CMS-65006
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.internal.util.ErrorUtils.handleServerException(ErrorUtils.java:56)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.dao.impl.CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.getCORSConfigurationByTenantDomain(CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.java:76)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.service.internal.impl.CORSManagerImpl.getCORSConfiguration(CORSManagerImpl.java:93)
csm-wso2-is               |     ... 22 more
csm-wso2-is               | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.configuration.mgt.core.exception.ConfigurationManagementClientException: Configuration management feature is not enabled.
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.configuration.mgt.core.ConfigurationManagerImpl.checkFeatureStatus(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:809)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.configuration.mgt.core.ConfigurationManagerImpl.getResource(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:194)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.dao.impl.CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.getResource(CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.java:123)
csm-wso2-is               |     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.dao.impl.CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.getCORSConfigurationByTenantDomain(CORSConfigurationDAOImpl.java:67)
```

What Am I doing wrong? I've checked if the table and user exist.

Comment: Did you populated the MySQL database with the SQL script? (in the dbscript folder)

Comment: There has being a change in `cors` in `WSO2IS-5.11.0`, https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/cors-with-wso2-identity-server-5.11/

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa Where can I find the new script for 5.11.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using db scripts from an older version. WSO2-IS 5.11.0 needs IDN_CONFIG_TYPE, IDN_CONFIG_RESOURCE, IDN_CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE and IDN_CONFIG_FILE tables.